# Why doesn't Engineering support MathJax syntax?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, formatting

There are a number of communities in the Stack Exchange network that use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to allow for rendering of mathematical expressions. Some that come to mind are Math and Physics.

In my opinion, Engineering would greatly benefit from allowing such syntax in questions and answers in this community as well.

Was this a deliberate decision not to support MathJax? Or is it simply that additional work is required to enable it? If the latter, what action can we take to help that get accomplished?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MathJax is off by default. However, I suspect this site will have plenty of uses for mathematical notation, so:

$$off \rightarrow on$$

Comment: Well that was fast :) Thanks!